# Analytical calculation of the resulting surface between a sphere and a spherical cap from another sphere

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

Let's say I have one spherical cap, resulting from cutting a sphere centered at origin and with radius `R1` with a plane, whose normal goes into the direction of the `x` axis. The spherical cap can be seen as a body with two surfaces, a planar surface and a spherical surface with total area equal to `S1`.
Now I have a second sphere, centered at another arbitrary point and with radius `R2`. In the cases in which the spherical cap and the second sphere overlap, dividing the spherical face of the cap into two parts with resulting values for the partial spherical surfaces `S1a` and `S1b`, how can one calculate analytically `S1a` and `S1b`?

Comment: The question is not clear. What does it mean, to calculate a surface? Are you trying to calculate an area? a volume? something else?

Comment: clarified, thanks for the correction